# Error in Opening Electron App in Mac:"file:///Applications/../Contents/Resources/app.asar/dist/index.html"

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder

I have build the electron app for mac but when I ran it , it is giving the below error

"Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Applications/e-admin.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/dist/index.html".

Here are the steps I did.

1) electron-builder build --mac
It created the following files are dist folder. 
a) e-admin-0.0.0.dmg , e-admin-0.0.0-mac.zip,index.html and a mac folder
b) in mac folder I could see mac/e-admin.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar file( not the folder)

2) I double clicked and installed  the e-admin-0.0.0.dmg and moved to application folder.
3) Opened the app.

Do I have to do any thing with app.asar file?(unpack or some thing?) or any etc procedure to make it work?

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "e-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p electron:serve ng:serve",
    "build": "npm run electron:serve-tsc && ng build",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
    "ng:serve": "ng serve",
    "ng:serve:web": "ng serve -c web -o",
    "electron:serve-tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig-serve.json",
    "electron:serve": "wait-on http-get://localhost:4200/ && npm run electron:serve-tsc && electron . --serve",
    "electron:local": "npm run build:prod && electron .",
    "electron:linux": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --linux",
    "electron:windows": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --windows",
    "electron:mac": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --mac",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "npm run build:prod && cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT='e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json' mocha --timeout 300000 --require ts-node/register e2e/**/*.e2e.ts",
    "version": "conventional-changelog -i CHANGELOG.md -s -r 0 && git add CHANGELOG.md",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {...}
```

and angular.josn file

```
"projects": {
    "eAdmin": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
....
```

main.ts contains

```
if (serve) {
    require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
      electron: require(`${__dirname}/node_modules/electron`)
    });
    win.loadURL('http://localhost:4200');
  } else {
    win.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After muiltple trial and error, The following changes worked for me

1) index.html

```
`<base href="/">`
```

to

```
<base href="./">
```

2) in main.ts, change the directory name dist to something else

from :

```
win.loadURL(url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),     
  protocol: 'file:',
  slashes: true
}));
```

To:

```
win.loadURL(url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'angular_build/index.html'),     
  protocol: 'file:',
  slashes: true
}));
```

3) Angular.js

```
"outputPath": "dist/",
```

to

```
"outputPath": "angular_build/",
```

Although I have seen suggesions to change step 2 & 3 , I was quite skepitcal.
Looks like dist directlory some how does not work and have to change to some thing like as mentioned above